# Why am I getting minor calculation discrepancies in my investment projection PHP program? (Looping and condition problem.)

Tags: php, algorithm

Good day to all. The program is supposed to get the ending balance each day, add the generated interest, and make a deposit every 30 days. The images show the output I'm supposed to get and the output I get.

[image]

```
 <?php
            for($i = $startingAge + 1; $i <= 65; $i++)
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo round($endingBalance, 2); ?></td>
                    <?php
                        for($j = 1; $j <= 365; $j++)
                        {

                            if($j == 365)
                            {
                                $dayAccum += 5;
                            }
                            if($dayAccum == 30)
                            {
                                $endingBalance += $thirtyDayDeposit;
                                $depositsMade += $thirtyDayDeposit;
                                $dayAccum = 0;
                            }
                            $interest = $endingBalance * (($interestRate / 100) / 365);
                            $endingBalance += $interest;
                            $interestGenerated += $interest;
                            //12 deposits need to be made every year except on the 6th year (1300)
                            if($j % 30 == 0)
                            {
                                $endingBalance += $thirtyDayDeposit;
                                $depositsMade += $thirtyDayDeposit;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>                      
                    <td><?php echo round($interestGenerated, 2); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo round($depositsMade, 2); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo round($endingBalance, 2); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                $interestGenerated = 0;
                $depositsMade = 0;
            }
```

Comment: "supposed to get" based on what exactly? Also, when is interest compounded?

Comment: My instructors program gets that output. I'm sorry the lines are not numbered but the interest is compounded $endingBalance += $interest; It is after the second IF statement.

Comment: I meant how often, not where in the code.  Daily? Monthly? Annually?

Comment: What does `$dayAccum` represent? Why do you do `$dayAccum += 5;` when `$j == 365`?

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Interest is compounded every day at 12% annually, thus (12 / 100) / 365) to get the daily percentage. $dayAccum is used to keep track of the 5 days that are left over every year because a deposit is made every 30 days in a year.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's made clear in your assignment specs, but your professor is obviously not calculating interest on new deposits the day they happen.  So move your interest logic above your deposit logic (right now you have it between the two parts of the deposit logic, it should be above _both_ parts)

Comment: I'll ask him to ensure that he doesn't want us to take into consideration interest on the day of deposits. However, your input fixed the problem. Thank you so much and enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's recommendation solved the problem.

> I'm not sure if it's made clear in your assignment specs, but your professor is obviously not calculating interest on new deposits the day they happen. So move your interest logic above your deposit logic (right now you have it between the two parts of the deposit logic, it should be above both parts) – Patrick Q